# Seria possivel incluir uma tag `morfema`?

Tags: discussion

Eu gostava de levantar a questão se a comunidade acha útil e pertinente incluir uma tag [morfemas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morfemas) no stackexchange em Português?

Pergunto isto por várias razões:

1. Sempre gostei de tentar pensar em termos de morfemas - ou análise morfémica, se preferirem.
2. Acho que todos os falantes do Português, por ser uma língua com elevada inflexão, terão uma predisposição/intuição a pensar em termos de morfemas.
3. Tenho visto relativamente pouca coisa na literatura Portuguesa e Brasileira sobre os morfemas. Por vezes, tenho visto autores consagrados que ao publicarem sobre os morfemas não convencem, ou não me satisfazem.
4. Trago a forte impressão que os morfemas em Português historicamente foram considerados um assunto a evitar.
5. Tentei procurar no site linguistics do stackexchange sobre morfemas e o panorama não é muito melhor. Muito pouca coisa.
6. A ausência da tag [morfemas](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morfemas) desencoraja contribuições específicas sobre o assunto.

Enfim, acho que vale a pena lançar a ideia. Estou interessado no que os membros da comunidade queiram contribuir sobre os morfemas em Português.

Comment: bad_coder, se queres usar a tag põe-lhe uma descrição. https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/348 Como está, não entendo o âmbito dela.

Comment: Prezado @ANeves, eu vou escrever a descrição não só dessa tag, como também de outras. Só não escrevi já porque ainda não tive tempo, escrever wikis de tags é um exercício canónico que exige alguma pesquisa e reflexão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A criação de uma tag deve aparecer associada a perguntas sobre ela porque a tag deve ser consequência do conteúdo, e não o inverso. Até porque, uma tag sem perguntas é eliminada pelo sistema automaticamente.

Acho muito interessante que queira que esse assunto esteja no site, mas a melhor forma de a tag aparecer é haver perguntas sobre esse tema. Se já houver é só dizer, cria-se a tag e associa-se às perguntas. Dei +1 por levantar esse assunto que me parece interessante para o site.